# Why is Python's "while next(iterator,False)" 400 times faster than "for i in someList"?

Tags: python, performance, loops, iterator

I am brand new to python and am concerned I am doing something wrong.
The below test seems to show that explicitly using an iterator to loop using the construct

`while next(iterator,False)`

is **400 times faster** than the evidently more pythonic

`for i in somelist`

,whether that be in a loop or a list comprehension.

The output of this test is

```
while(next)                 -> Iterations = 100,000    listLength = 1,000    seconds =   0.012 seconds
iteration through the list  -> Iterations = 100,000    listLength = 1,000    seconds =   4.971 seconds
list comprehension          -> Iterations = 100,000    listLength = 1,000    seconds =   3.704 seconds
```

Is this a result of the latter two methods doing `try except` in the inner loop?
Seems like too big a difference when the list is 1000 elements long an an exception is only therefore thrown 0.10% of the time!

Is it something else? Including a gross error on my part?

```
import time

ITER = 100000

for listLength in range(1000,1001,100):

    inputs =[1] * listLength
    #print(inputs)

    #check with if test
    i = iter(inputs)
    newlist=[]
    print(newlist)
    startTime = time.perf_counter()
    for j in range(0,ITER):
        theInput = next(i,False) #This is on 3.6 and assignment is not an expression until 3.8, hence this line being in two places
        while theInput:
            newlist.append( 1/theInput)
            theInput = next(i,False)

    print('while(next)-> Iterations = {:,}    listLength = {:,}    seconds =  {:6.3f} seconds'
          .format(ITER,listLength,time.perf_counter() - startTime) )


    #check just iterating therough the list which presumably does a try except
    startTime = time.perf_counter()
    for j in range(0,ITER):
        for theInput in inputs:
            x = 1/theInput


    print('pythonic iteration through the list  -> Iterations = {:,}    listLength = {:,}    seconds =  {:6.3f} seconds'
          .format(ITER,listLength,time.perf_counter() - startTime) )

    #check list comprehension
    startTime = time.perf_counter()
    for j in range(0,ITER):
        newlist =[1/theInput for theInput in inputs]

    print('pythonic list comprehension  -> Iterations = {:,}    listLength = {:,}    seconds =  {:6.3f} seconds'
          .format(ITER,listLength,time.perf_counter() - startTime) )
```

Comment: You need to put the `i = iter(inputs)` inside the `for j in range(0, ITER)` loop.

Comment: During the while-loop method, *i* gets exhausted during the first iteration of *j*. The remaining iterations of *j* for *ITER* (100000) do effectively nothing.

Comment: To go with Mateen's comment, `for theInput in inputs` implicitly calls `iter(inputs)` each time the loop starts; that's 100,000 calls you *aren't*  making in your `while` check.

Comment: also the 'pythonic iteration' does not build up `newlist`

Comment: I ran a fixed version of your test and I get `while -> 19 seconds` and `pythonic -> 6 seconds`.

Comment: Yes, you are all absolutely right. User error. Thanks for the help with this.List comprehension now clearly fastest